# Error unknown time zone America/Los_Angeles in time.LoadLocation

Tags: docker, go, time, dockerfile

even through CoreOS shows America/Los_Angeles when timedatectl list-timezones, why does Docker throw error **unknown time zone America/Los_Angeles** ?

Is there something else need to be done when LoadLocation called running inside a container or anything that can be added to Docker file so it can point to zoneinfo ?

from [godoc](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#LoadLocation)

> The time zone database needed by LoadLocation may not be present on all systems, especially non-Unix systems. LoadLocation looks in the directory or uncompressed zip file named by the ZONEINFO environment variable, if any, then looks in known installation locations on Unix systems, and finally looks in $GOROOT/lib/time/zoneinfo.zip.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

For anyone looking for an answer, this helped me.

adding these two line to docker file , (final if it's a 2 stage build)

```
ADD https://github.com/golang/go/raw/master/lib/time/zoneinfo.zip /zoneinfo.zip
ENV ZONEINFO /zoneinfo.zip
```

Comment: have you tried this: https://coreos.com/os/docs/latest/configuring-date-and-timezone.html ? You can also use alpine linux, instead of coreos.

Comment: It seems a bit fragile if you can't run a go executable without setting this environment variable! What other environment variables do we need to set if we're using the product of a golang docker image build?

Comment: You can also add to Dockerfile `RUN apk add --no-cache tzdata` instead, appears to work after that.

Comment: Note that the original question was about CoreOS, and not Alpine (which is using `apk`). The solution given was pretty generic.

Answer (score 1):

David Thomas' answer did the trick for me:

```
RUN apk add --no-cache tzdata
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31259647)

Answer (score 0):

I hope you are all safe! I experienced the issue with `go test time` (or `go test all`) failing with

`panic: cannot load America/Los_Angeles for testing: unknown time zone America/Los_Angeles; you may want to use -tags=timetzdata`

It seems that the test tries to read the file `zoneinfo.zip` from the non-existing (hard-coded?) directory `/usr/lib/go-1.18/lib/time`. I found a workaround and added it to my `Containerfile` / `Dockerfile`. Let me know, if you have a more elegant solution.

**Used version:**

- go version go1.18.1 linux/amd64
- Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS

**Workaround in Containerfile / Dockerfile:**

```
RUN mkdir -p /usr/lib/go-1.18/lib/time
ADD https://github.com/golang/go/raw/master/lib/time/zoneinfo.zip /usr/lib/go-1.18/lib/time/zoneinfo.zip
RUN chown -R openvscode-server:openvscode-server /usr/lib/go-1.18/lib/time
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative for this is to simply import "time/tzdata" into your go code -- see this [godoc](https://pkg.go.dev/time/tzdata).
Note too that this is included in the description of godoc referenced in the initial question -- in `LoadLocation` where the forth bullet of where it is loaded is

> the time/tzdata package, if it was imported

(but note this has likely changed since the question was posed).